# Selecting a Check Box puts Today's date on same row 6 cells to the right

Tags: excel, vba

I designing a form in Excel 2010 to enter the date each task in a list is completed by checking a "YES" form control box. I have assigned the cell underneath each form control box as the cell link for that box and I want the macro to start in that cell and then offset to the right 6 cells and put today's date. The offset function isn't hard but I don't know how to get the macro to start in the linked cell because clicking the box doesn't select the cell so the active cell object doesn't seem to work for me. Because the row is different for each box the range object needs to change depending upon which box I check otherwise I am back to writing code for every row.

The second problem is if the box is already checked, I don't want it to change to today every time I open the workbook. Once I check it, it should put in the date and then stay the same from then on. This is probably simple but I can't seem to get it right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using the object and event navigation dropdowns above the code editor, add a CheckBox Changed event for each of your checkboxes in order to set the active cell to the appropriate one each time a checkbox is clicked.  You can also perform your validation ensuring the checkbox is currently selected at this time.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(x, y).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Where `x` and `y` are the appropriate values for your implementation.  If you have a lot of checkboxes, I would recommend encapsulating this logic into a common function and calling it from the various checkbox changed events to clean up your code, but this method will get you the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Assign this macro (in a regular module) to all your checkboxes:

```
Sub CheckBoxUpdated()

Dim cb As CheckBox

    On Error Resume Next
    Set cb = ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects(Application.Caller)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not cb Is Nothing Then
        If cb.Value = 1 Then
           ActiveSheet.Range(cb.LinkedCell).Offset(0, 6).Value = Date
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```